# SSLv3 Disable on Tomcat 7 64 bit jre6

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7, tls1.2, jrecorder

To disable the SSLv3, we made the required changes in server.xml,but after that Application page is not opening after selecting TLS1.0,TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in the Internet options-->Advanced. PFB the Server.xml section in which changes were made:

```
Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="250" 
connectionTimeout="90000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"     maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" maxThreads="500" minSpareThreads="50"  port="443"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\abc.keystore"
keystorePass="abc"
scheme="https" 
secure="true"
clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />  

    Earlier value of in the above mentioned Server.xml was sslProtocol="TLSv1"
```

Comment: Check for error messages at the server side (i.e. Tomcat). JRE6 used for the Tomcat does not support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

Comment: We tried to access the application on TLS1.0 after disabling SSLv3.0, but it's not accessible on TLS1.0 also.

Comment: It might be that the application simply throws an error and does not start properly because you've tried to configure protocols which are not supported. That's why I recommended for looking at errors at the server side.

Comment: After restarting Tomcat, getting below error:          SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSSLContext(JSSESocketFactory.java:472)at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:492)

Comment: Due to Comment Character restriction, added starting lines of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\abc.keystore"
> ...
> sslProtocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
> ```

It looks like one tries to use TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 with Java 6. But this Java version is old, unsupported for years (and probably insecure) and has no support for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

> ```
> ... NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
> ```

And because of this missing support for modern TLS version it will be unable to start with this configuration. Which means that you either need to upgrade your Java version or configure Tomcat to use TLSv1 only.

Comment: Earlier Server.xml was having sslProtocol="TLSv1" /> only,I made the changes to disable SSLV3. Please let me know, what changes i need to do to disable sslv3, but  to enable the access on TLS1.0

Comment: @Rathin: If sslProtocol is set to TLSv1 only than SSLv3 is already disabled.

Comment: Sorry, for my previous update.   Earlier Server.xml was having sslProtocol="TLS" />, we tried changing to sslProtocol="TLSV1" /> , but then also application is not accessible on TLS 1.0. Do we need to make any additional change to make it accessible?

Comment: @Rathin: change it back to "TLS" only. SSLv3 should not be covered by this setting. Did you checked before you made all this changes if the application was accessible by SSLv3 at all?

Comment: With sslProtocol="TLS" />, it was accessible on sslv3, we verified by selecting sslv3 and deselecting  sslv2, TLS1.0 ,TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in internet option -->Advanced section

Comment: @Rathin: I'm not sure if this test really  did what you expected. Also I don't know if you really connected directly to the tomcat instance and not to some server in front of the Tomcat. Also check the value of sslEnabledProtocols 
 setting. And read https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE including the notice about ignoring sslEnabledProtocols  in specific versions of Tomcat.

Comment: sslEnabledProtocols setting resolved the issue, we made following changes sslProtocol="TLS" 
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1"/>, Thanks for your support Steffen.